# Router suddenly stopped port forwarding

Tags: networking, router, vpn, dd-wrt

I got a second router today (Linksys WRT54GL), and put DD-WRT on it. I was going to use the router as a PPTP server bridged to my main router, which worked for a little while.

Now however, my main router (TP-LINK WDR4300) doesn't seem to forward ports any more. I tried forwarding multiple ports to multiple devices but nothing worked. I can connect to the VPN using the local IP of the router (set it to static). When I try to connect using my main router's IP it fails.

I've tried following multiple guides on the Internet and multiple programs to help me with the issue but to no avail. The local IP of my main router is 192.168.0.1 with DHCP clients ranging from 192.168.0.100 to 192.168.0.199. My second router's static IP is 192.168.0.2, so no conflicts there.

I performed a factory reset of my main router, disabled my laptop's and both routers' firewalls but that didn't help either. I really don't know what to do, so I'm hoping somebody here can give me some advice.

**EDIT:** I have NAT enabled. I also tried DMZ with no success either.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to check:

First, realize that PPTP is a trickier case than run-of-the-mill port forwarding, because it doesn't just use a port number of well-known transport-layer protocols TCP or UDP, it also uses a whole other transport layer protocol called GRE (IP protocol number 47). So when testing port mapping, put up a web server on port 80 and test that. That's a simple TCP-based protocol that should always work. If that works but PPTP doesn't, it may be that your router doing the port forwarding isn't smart enough about PPTP.

Second, realize that many if not most NAT gateways don't handle "hairpin NAT" very well. That's when a private LAN-side client tries to connect to the gateway's public IP address, and needs that connection attempt to get forwarded via a port mapping back into a server on the private LAN side. So when testing port mapping, it's a good idea to test from a machine that's on the WAN side of your NAT gateway, not something on the LAN side.

Comment: I know my router is capable of it, I tried it right after I set it up and it worked like a charm. Even went to my grandfather to test it on his connection. And the times I did test it at home, I did it over WAN, not LAN.

My router doesn't have options for protocol forwarding which might be a problem.